# Histogram aggregation on averaged field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents that looks like

```
[
  {
    "price": 10,
    "market.id": 1,
    "product.id": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 2,
    "market.id": 3,
    "product.id": 1
  },
  {
    "price": 5,
    "market.id": 3,
    "product.id": 2
  }
]
```

In order to count the number of market in a given average price interval,I made this ES query :

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "term": {
          "price": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "price_ranges": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "price",
        "interval": 0.5,
        "min_doc_count": 0,
        "extended_bounds": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 45
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "market_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "market.id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem here, is that doesn't take the average price but the price for each interval.

I don't know if it's possible to do this directly with an ES query.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "average price interval"

Comment: first of all, thanks for trying to help. I've updated my documents to expose the product.id.
I would like, to have an average price per product and then, count the number of market in a given interval.

In others words, i would like to have the field as average :
"histogram": {
        "field": "AVG(price)"
        }

Comment: Ok thanks, I get it now